# How to quickly identify whether a jQuery function returns one elment or a set?

Tags: javascript, jquery

It seems that some jQuery functions will return one element, while others will return a set.

For example, in the following statement:

```
$('.class1').parents(".class2").next().next().find(".class3").show(500);
```

`$('.class1'), parents(".class2"), find(".class3")` will return a set.
while `next()` will return a single element.

It is really hard to identify which will return a single element, and which will return a set. Sometimes, its name will imply, such as `parents()` will return a set, but `parent()` will return a single element unless its is called on a set. But sometimes, the name is also ambiguous, such as find(). And it seems that one need to read the document carefully to identify this, this is no highlighted "Return result:" in the help document of jQuery such as https://api.jquery.com/next/ and https://api.jquery.com/parent/, the only clue is the description like 'Get the **parent** of each element' or 'Get the **immediately following sibling** of' to indicate a single element, and 'Get the descendant**s** of each element' to indicate a set.

So, my question is, is there a simple way to easily identify whether a jQuery function will return a single value or a set?

Comment: All of then return a jQuery object. A jQuery object always has a `length` property. That length could be 0, meaning there are no elements, 1, meaning there is a single element, or more than 1, meaning there are multiple elements. You act on all of them the same way in most cases, so why does it matter? You should be constructing your selectors and statements such that it is obvious how many elements are being affected. The statment shown tells me the code is fragile; change one element in the DOM and it will break. The code should be more resilient.

Answer (score 0):

I think the short and simple answer is No.

There is no intuitive way to tell if a jQuery selector will return a single element or a set as you mentioned in your post... the same selector can return either.

It truly depends on the construction of the DOM.

For instance, in the expression:

`$('.class1').parents(".class2").next().next().find(".class3").show(500);`

This will return only 1 element, if there happens to be only one element with class name = "class3" under the parent of `$('.class1').parents(".class2").next().next()`

To force this same expression to return only the first, you have to specify more restrictions on the selector:

`$('.class1').parents(".class2").next().next().find(".class3:nth-child(1)").show(500);`